# Dropping list elements from nested list after evaluation

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I need to create a new list from a nested list but using the evaluation as criteria to drop the elements. For example let's say that that I have the following list:

```
list1={{1,1,-(-1)^3,x,2*x},{1,1,(-1)^3,x,2*x},
       {1,1,x,2*x,3*x},{1,1,-x,-2*x,-3*x}}
```

and I need to eliminate the elements of `list1` that the absolute value of the third element give $1$, i.d. $-(-1)^3$ and $(-1)^3$, to obtain

```
 list2={{1,1,x,2*x,3*x},{1,1,-x,-2*x,-3*x}}
```

In this case, `list1` was created with the code

```
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++,
    For[j = 1, j < 4, j++,  
  list1[i, j, p_] = Sort[Eigenvalues[mat[i, j, p]]];
  ]  ]
```

I have been trying to use `Select` but until now I am not been able to create `list2` to plot it with

```
list2=ParallelTable[Select[Abs[eigval[i, j, p][[3]]], 
                       Abs[#] != 1 &] , {i, 1, 4}, {j,1,4}]
```

I am still learning to uses cases in Mathematica so I am not sure how to do it. Do you know if there is wise way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you prefer using `DeleteCases`,

```
list2 = DeleteCases[list1, _?(Abs[#[[3]]] == 1 &)]
```

> {{1, 1, x, 2 x, 3 x}, {1, 1, -x, -2 x, -3 x}}

Answer (score 6):

```
Delete[
 list1, 
 Position[Abs[list1[[All, 3]]], 1]
 ]
```

> {{1, 1, x, 2 x, 3 x}, {1, 1, -x, -2 x, -3 x}}

Answer (score 6):

if you want to use `Select`, try this

```
Select[list1,!NumberQ@#[[3]]||Abs[#[[3]]]!=1&]
```

> {{1, 1, x, 2 x, 3 x}, {1, 1, -x, -2 x, -3 x}}

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty efficient on unpacked arrays (the `Listable` attribute assumes `list1[[All, 3]]` is a flat list, as it is in the OP's example):

```
Block[{signal},
 SetAttributes[signal, Listable];
 signal[1] = 1; signal[_] = 0;
 Pick[list1, signal@Abs[list1[[All, 3]]], 0]
 ]
(*  {{1, 1, x, 2 x, 3 x}, {1, 1, -x, -2 x, -3 x}}  *)
```

(For packed arrays, one would probably want to use `Unitize[x-1]` instead of `signal`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
  {{1, 1, -(-1)^3, x, 2*x},
   {1, 1, (-1)^3, x, 2*x},
   {1, 1, x, 2*x, 3*x},
   {1, 1, -x, -2*x, -3*x}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3}

```
First @ SequenceSplit[list, {{_, _, 1 | -1, __}}]
```

{{1, 1, x, 2 x, 3 x}, {1, 1, -x, -2 x, -3 x}}

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = {{1, 1, -(-1)^3, x, 2*x}, {1, 1, (-1)^3, x, 2*x}, 
      {1, 1, x, 2*x, 3*x}, {1, 1, -x, -2*x, -3*x}};
```

Using `Cases` and `Except` with `Condition`:

```
Cases[l1, {_, _, Except[a_ /; Abs[a] == 1], __}, ∞]
```

> `{{1, 1, x, 2 x, 3 x}, {1, 1, -x, -2 x, -3 x}}`

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[l1, {s : {_, _, Except[a_ /; Abs[a] == 1], __}} :> s]
```

> `{{1, 1, x, 2 x, 3 x}, {1, 1, -x, -2 x, -3 x}}`